# Windows 7 Media Center mixes up thumbnails of music albums

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

I'm using the Windows 7 Media Center on Home Premium.

Usually everything is running nicely, but sometimes the media center messes up the thumbnails of music album. Suddenly a few thumbs have moved to some other album folders, without apparent reason.

This is not due to automatic thumbnail update from the internet. The thumbnails are switched, messed up, not single ones updated, but swapped instead.

When playing a song from the album, it does show the right thumb, they are switched only for the thumbnail, not for the big view.
After closing Media Center and starting it again, the right thumbs are displayed again, so this seems to be due to some internal caching error.

Is there a bug fix for this somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like it's just your cache getting a little corrupted.

go to

`C:\Users\*USERNAME*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player`

and delete files named similar to 'CurrentDatabase_***.wmdb' & 'LocalMLS_*.wmdb' and it will automatically rebuild the cache, which usually also involves downloading album art from the net.